# Hvac electric furnace Nordyne E1EH-012HA

Tags: hvac

I have a problem with Nordyne electric furnace with A/c coil above. It started the winter short cycling, then did nothing.

I became a YouTube maniac trying to figure out the problem. I first replaced the main breaker as the bottom one felt loose. Nothing.

Then I ordered a single stack sequencer, limit switch, control board and the wiring harness with the 3 connections. Okay, now if I turn the breaker on, the blower and one or more elements come on and will run until I kill the breaker.

Got a new thermostat, no difference.

If I completely disconnect all wires from the control board it makes no difference so it works like a space heater with complete disregard for the thermostat. I don’t have a separate relay but I think it might be mounted on the control board itself.

I have searched for shorted wires, traced out wires from the diagram until I’m ready to pull hair, if drinking would help, I’d be drunk! Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated!

T[wiring diagram](https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn%3Aaaid%3Ascds%3AUS%3Ae04765b9-689b-45d5-b555-f9b38cd60b77)

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace?

Comment: How cold has it been? Is it a heat pump?

Comment: I’m in Louisiana, in the 40’s today. 32 forecast for tonight. It is not a heat pump.

Comment: I’ve been using YouTube for help but I can’t find a video showing how to troubleshoot my control board. At this point, I don’t know what else it could be. Anyone?